# Default selection for a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I made a `ComboBox` from where a language can be selected and when selected this would work as if the form changes the language.

However, the default `SelectedIndex` is -1. Now, this would make sense if I hadn't declared otherwise in the `Form.Load` sub.

In the `Load` function I've added the following:

```vb
cbbLanguage.SelectedIndex = My.Settings.Language
```

`cbbLanguage` is the name of the `ComboBox` and in the Application Settings the default setting of `Language` (which is an Integer) is 0.

So from my understanding this should be equivalent to:

```vb
cbbLanguage.SelectedIndex = 0
```

While debugging I notice that the Index is not changed regardless of setting the `SelectedIndex` before.

The Combobox has 2 Items `(German[0] English[1])` so the default should be German.

Also,

```vb
cbblanguage.Text = "Example"
```

does not work, even if the index is on -1

Items of the Combobox are made here:

[image: Image of UI]

```vb
Private Sub options_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)Handles MyBase.Load
    txtDownloadPath.Text = My.Settings.DownloadPath.ToString()
    chkboxStandardInfo.SetItemChecked(0,My.Settings.chkboxSysteminfo)
    chkboxStandardInfo.SetItemChecked(1,My.Settings.chkboxIPconfigInfo)
    chkboxStandardInfo.SetItemChecked(2,My.Settings.chkboxPrinterInfo)

    chkboxAutoStart.Checked = My.Settings.AutoGetInfo

    cbbLanguage.Items.Add("German")
    cbbLanguage.Items.Add("English")
    cbbLanguage.SelectedIndex = My.Settings.Language 'this is an integer / 0

    MsgBox(cbbLanguage.SelectedIndex, 0, "test") 'Index is always -1 Idk why
End Sub
```

I don't know if it's interesting or weird but `items.add("...")` does not work either, I don't know what I've done but ComboBox just won't work at all.

If something is unclear please let me know so I can / will provide the information.

Comment: Maybe `My.Settings.Language` is stored as string.  Write `cbbLanguage.SelectedIndex = CInt(My.Settings.Language)`. This will throw an exception if the string does not represent a valid `Integer`. You should also set `Option Strict On` to have the compiler tell you about possible invalid conversions. If this does not help, set a [breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022) on this line and watch the value of `My.Settings.Language`.

Comment: Note also that you must set the index to 0 after you have added items to the ComboBox.

Comment: Hey Oliver first o fall, Thanks for getting my spelling mistakes out xD

Comment: Language is save/made in the Application Settings as an Integer would suprise me if that still turn out to be a string, I can try a few more things tomorrow as I am home now and not sure if I can RDP to my work pc but I will go and for sure put on option Strict and the items for the combobox are made in the, ehh I am german sorry I dont know the word, "draft-page-properties of the combobox  "? so I am actually not 100% sure when the items being initialized. if you don't get what you mean I can maybe send an img to show it better

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes
ok so "Language" is an Integer and "CInt(My.Settings.Language)" doesn't change anything either.
I am going to try to make the Item list somewhere else to see if that works
if you or someonelse got any other idea I can try out please let me know

Comment: I am not saying that you are doing things wrong. I am just guessing what might have gone wrong. What can really help, is to do further investigation at the location where you are setting the `SelectedIndex`. Place a breakpoint there and see the value of `cbbLanguage.Items.Count`. Then watch the value of `SelectedIndex` before and after it is assigned. Watch the value of `My.Settings.Language`. See: [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Problem has been found and fixed.
the issue here was that I overlooked my function

```vb
cbbLanguage.SelectedIndexChanged
```

I made a refresh of the form here and so of course when on load the combobox is changed the event fires and sort of blocks of the change I originally wanted to make...
ah well so more you know